# How many syllables are there in "world" in American English?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

How many syllables are there in the word **"world"** when pronounced in American English? I know it depends on the speaker but I don't have any specific pronunciation I can show. But generally, most Americans pronounce it as if it is a two syllable word. Like **/wə.rəld/**. I have heard that the R makes a syllable on its own. Does it happen in the word "world" when pronounced in American English?

[Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/world) gives the transcription **\ˈwər(-ə)ld/**, it shows two vowels (2 **ə**) and two vowels often mean two syllables. And if you listen to the pronunciation, it sounds like two syllables.

Comment: You may find the following source helpful:     https://examples.yourdictionary.com/diphthong-examples.html

Answer (score 1):

A word can comprise several phonemes yet still only be a single syllable. Pronunciation guides break words down but not necessarily into syllables. A syllable *usually* contains a vowel. There is only one vowel in "world", and the word has only one syllable.

You're right that different English dialects pronounce words differently, and as a native British English speaker, I agree that US English speakers tend to draw out vowels. There are some British dialects that also roll the R sound which can make the word "world" sound like two 'beats'. But the fact that is *can* be pronounced as a single syllable kind of proves that is *is* a single-syllable word, just some people draw it out.

> The world of haikus
> proves that the word in question
> has one syllable.

Comment: I don't think I'm confusing "syllables" and "phonemes". I know what a phoneme is and I also know what a syllable is. My question is about 'syllables" not phonemes. Consider the word "pot" = /p/ + /ɒ/ + /t/: three phonemes, but one syllable. Now "Astralbee", suppose, AS-TRAL-BEE: three syllables. Of course the number of syllable may vary if you pronounce it differently but generally, it's true.

Comment: @Sphinx Good example. And each of the three syllables of my username has at least one vowel in it. "World" has one vowel in it, and one syllable.

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying. But if you hear the pronunciation, most Americans pronounce it as if there are two vowels in it.

Comment: @Sphinx Your question is "how many syllables" are there in the word, so the answer is one. How many syllables in the word "go"? One. In Bohemian Rhapsody, Queen sang "let me go-o-o-o-o-o-o".... but it's still only got one syllable.

Comment: Remember that the OP is asking about 'world' as used in American, not in English. It could easily be two syllables 'woh-ruld', the same way that 'nuclear' can be three syllables 'nu-ku-lahr'

Comment: @PcMan Firstly, there's no such language as 'American'. You mean BrEng and AmEng, and my answer acknowledges both. I also discuss the fact that words can be pronounced with differing numbers of syllables either due to differing accents, or for poetic reasons. Some pronunciations are just incorrect, however. "Nuclear" is an odd example - you could have just said "ear".

Comment: @Astralbee: A more interesting example is "fire", which can be a bit confusing in sheet music when split over two notes.  Some songs may treat "fire" as having two syllables, pronounced "fi" and "uhr", but simply hyphenating the word would make it look as though the second syllable is pronounced "ray".

Comment: @Astralbee I think you're confusing the single, "drawn out" syllable in some other words like **furled** and **hurled** with the genuine second syllable which **world** has (and the others don't). Just like "deer" and "near" have 1 syllable, but "clear" has 2. Some may pronounce both groups of three words such that all in each group rhyme with each other, but that's not the pronunciation OP is asking about. "World" = "wur-uld"; "Clear" = "clee-yer"; they are both **said** with two syllables even though they are **not written that way**.

Comment: @PcMan "Nuclear" *always* has 3 syllables (unless you pronounce the word "clear" on its own as only 1, which is less common here) - but the second should be "clee," not "ku." Like **new-clee-yer**.

Comment: @Astralbee It seems like the differentiator is that the "**ea**" in "clear" is not actually a diphthong like it is in "near": instead, to transcribe it accurately, there should be an umlaut over the **a**. For "world," as OP's dictionary link shows, the second syllable comes from the insertion of an extra vowel not reflected in the word's spelling. It's a schwa sound.

Comment: Related: the last paragraph in this answer: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/505791/480457